# SIMD optimization for IIR filtering

Tags: filtering, signal-processing, simd, cortex-m

Having 2 16-bit input channels with an actual full depth of 12 bits, I need the most efficient implementation of an IIR filter. ARM has created a [SIMD implementation for a direct form 1 bi-quad cascade filtering](https://github.com/NordicPlayground/mbed/blob/master/libraries/dsp/cmsis_dsp/FilteringFunctions/arm_biquad_cascade_df1_fast_q15.c). My question is there a clear and simple method for implementing an arbitrary order filter for a single channel/ two channels? For example, I would like to implement a 3rd order filter using SIMD